# Set dynamically array of numbers into array or container c++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

im looking for away to minimize the need to declare array each time i like to 
define hard coded array for example if i need to set into vector element array with numbers

i need to :
where :

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > LineVectorBasic;
int arr1[] = {0,2 ,1,2 ,2,2 ,3,2 ,3,2};
LineVectorBasic.insert(LineVectorBasic.begin() + 0,setLineVector(arr1));
int arr2[] = {0,2 ,1,2 ,2,2 ,3,2 ,3,2};
LineVectorBasic.insert(LineVectorBasic.begin() + 1,setLineVector(arr2));  // X 5 or what ever ....
....
....
std::vector<int> LinesManager::setLineVector(int values[])
{
    std::vector<int> templine;
    for(int i=0; i<sizeof(values);i++)
    {
        templine.insert(templine.begin() + i, values[i]);
    }
    return templine;
}
```

can it be shorter ?

Comment: It needs to be correct first, `values` is a pointer (`int a[]` in a function declaration is the same as `int* a`), so `sizeof(values)` doesn't return the number of elements.

Comment: how can i get the size of array ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all this function is wrong

```
std::vector<int> LinesManager::setLineVector(int values[])
{
    std::vector<int> templine;
    for(int i=0; i<sizeof(values);i++)
    {
        templine.insert(templine.begin() + i, values[i]);
    }
    return templine;
}
```

`sizeof(values)` is not equal to the number of elements in the array passed as an argument to the function. It is equal to `sizeof( int * )` that is either to 4 or 8 bytes depending on used platform, You should explicitly pass this number of elements of the array to the function.

Instead of the function you could write simply expression

```
std::vector<int>( std::begin( arr ), std::end( arr ) );
```

That is enough.

Moreover you do not need even to use the array. You could write

```
std::vector<int>( {0,2 ,1,2 ,2,2 ,3,2 ,3,2} );
```

Aslo if arrays that used to initialize the vector have the same size then it is better to use standard class `std::array` because you may assign to it new initializer list. For example

```
std::array<int, 10> arr = {0,2 ,1,2 ,2,2 ,3,2 ,3,2};
std::vector<int>( std::begin( arr ), std::end( arr ) );
arr = { 5,2 ,3, 4 ,2, 2, 1, 2 ,6,2};
std::vector<int>( std::begin( arr ), std::end( arr ) );
```

Comment: the expression :LineVectorBasic.insert(LineVectorBasic.begin() + 0,std::vector<int>( {0,2 ,1,2 ,2,2 ,3,2 ,3,2} ));
give error: "expected expression "

Comment: @user63898 It seems that your compiler does not support std::initializer_list. In this case use the constructor with iterators.

Comment: thanks , the problem i need to init new array each time i set new vector i like to avoid this

Comment: Thanks vlad , but what if in one i need 10 elements and in the other array i will need 5 and in the other i will need 3 , is std::array<int, 10> ( with 10 elements ) still be vaild ?

Comment: @user63898 You should define the array of the maximum size and if an initializer list is shorter for example has only n elements then you can write std::vector<int>( std::begin( arr ), std::next( std::begin( arr ), n ) );

Comment: Thanks Allot for your help, but i have few problems it seams that visual studio 2012 dose not support std::array so i stuck

Comment: @user63898 You need simply to include header <array>

Comment: Thanks again this fixed the problem but now i have new one 
the number of elements needs to be constant , should i give max number array like  100? the array can be 6 size and can be 50 size and 99 ....

Comment: @user63898 Yes, you can.

Comment: ok now when i try to do for example :  arr={0,1 ,1,1 ,2,1 ,3,1 ,4,1};
it gives me error: expected expression
i defined the array like this:
const int ArraySize = 50;
    std::array<int,  ArraySize> arr;

Answer (score 0):

For each array, do this:

```
LineVectorBasic.emplace_back( std::begin(arr1), std::end(arr1) );
```

This constructs the vector in-place, using the costructor that takes two iterators. `std::begin` and `std::end` are utility functions that return iterators to the c-style array.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a C++11 compliant compiler, you can simply do:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > LineVectorBasic { {0,2 ,1,2 ,2,2 ,3,2 ,3,2}, {0,2 ,1,2 ,2,2 ,3,2 ,3,2}, {....} };
```